# Rotate nodes in SpriteKit before the scene displays

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit, nodes

I'm creating a game where there is a split screen view for 2 players.

The game is for an iPad and the the split screen will work in such way that each player will see the nodes right-side-up.
The way that the app works is that the upper half of the game will have all nodes rotated upside-down.

The problem I have is that when the scene is being loaded, none of the actions are being executed before the scene is fully in view.

For an instance, I'm using the following command to rotate one of the labels:

```
[self.player1Score runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:UP_SIDE_DOWN duration:0]];
```

The problem is that the rotation won't take place until the scene animation is done - which will make it look very strange as the nodes will rotate immediately once the scene is fully in view (I could animate them, but I prefer they load up already rotated properly).

I tried running this from both **initWithSize** and **didMoveToView** but the results were the same.

My only option at the moment is for the Textures to be duplicated and rotated using Photoshop - but I'd rather to have the app "lighter" and not have unnecessary graphics if I can help it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't u set SKNode's ***zRotation*** property to set the rotation as a the node is created, instead of rotating them using SKAction.

```
SKNode *node = [SKNode node];
node.zRotation = -M_PI/2.0;
```

Comment: In context of the OP's question, the code will be something like `self.player1Score.zRotation += UP_SIDE_DOWN;`

Comment: Oh my god. I was so into SKActions that I totally forgot that the node has the zRotation property. THANK YOU!